# How to produce a makefile that runs multiple programs after each other in c?

Tags: c, function, methods, compilation, makefile

I have written two programs. The first one, ProgramOne, creates inputfiles for the second program, ProgramTwo (The two programs have no files in common, the output written by ProgramOne is just the input of ProgramTwo). Sometimes running the first program takes some time, but on other times it takes just a few seconds, depending on the dimensions I am simulating at.

I would therefore like to put all my files into one folder and create a makefile that is able to make commands to run:

1. ProgramOne
2. ProgramTwo
3. The two programs right after each other

The first two are not that difficult to write, the third one is the problem however (So at the moment I am able to run ProgramOne, then run ProgramTwo, which takes me two commands in the terminal, but I would like to make this one command as well in some cases). How do I make clear to the compiler that I want the two programs executed after each other.

At the moment I have a fairly standard makefile, but I have written the following:

(**note** that programone.c contains a main function, and only a main-function, depending on nothing from SRCS (the files for ProgramTwo))

(**Another important note**: to run ProgramTwo, I need to specify some arguments. In the terminal I would write: `./RunProgramTwo -v results`. How do I need to specify these arguments whenever I would like to run the two programs after each other?)

(I also left some things out, like a clean and distclean command, but I do not think they are relevant to this case. If you think so however, I will provide my complete makefile upon request)

```
NVCC = nvcc
NVCFLAGS = -arch=sm_30
CFLAGS = -Wall -pedantic -g
LDLIBS = -lz -lpthread 
SRCS := allfiles.c
OBJS := allfiles.o
all: .depend RunProgramOne RunProgramTwo RunAll
RunProgramOne: $ programone.o
        ${NVCC} ${NVCFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} $^ -o $@
RunProgramTwo: ${OBJS} main.o
        ${NVCC} ${NVCFLAGS} ${LDLIBS} $^ -o $@
RunAll:  RunProgramOne RunProgramTwo
depend:
        ${NVCC} -M ${SRCS} > .depend
.depend: ${SRCS} makefile
        ${NVCC} -M ${SRCS} > .depend
```

This does not seem to do the job as I just get ProgramTwo running when I invoke ./RunAll.

Note that I am currently thinking of a solution where my two programs are decoupled from each other. I am also able to make the main-function in ProgramOne into a function, which I then invoke at the very beginning of the main-function of ProgramTwo. In this way, I can easily generate a makefile command for the third of my options, namely the RunAll, but then I do not know how I can achieve the first two.

I would prefer a solution such that my two programs are decoupled, but if this is not possible, feel free to tell me any possible way I can make this work.

I already looked up basic information about makefiles (simple tutorials) and looked at the manual for makefile itself, but I do not seem to find a solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ah, that I did not mention. **I would like them to run in the same terminal one after the other.**

Comment: I use the standard terminal in Ubuntu 14.04. I have however no idea which one that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This target doesn't run anything: it just declares prerequisites but you have no recipe (the recipe is the thing that's passed to the shell and executed):

```
RunAll:  RunProgramOne RunProgramTwo
```

If you want this target to run the programs you have to write a recipe that does this:

```
RunAll:  RunProgramOne RunProgramTwo
        ./RunProgramOne
        ./RunProgramTwo
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me, as invoking ./RunAll in the terminal gives me
`bash: ./RunAll: No such file or directory`
I forgot some important information in the question however, so I'll edit that as well.

Comment: You can't run `RunAll` as a command from your shell.  `RunAll` is a make target that lives in your makefile, and only the `make` program can process your makefile and build targets.  You have to type `make RunAll`.

Comment: If you want to be able to run both from your shell command line without invoking `make` then you can't just use a makefile target (clearly).  You can create a shell alias that will build and run them both, for example `alias RunAll='make RunAll'`

Comment: If you need to add arguments to the `RunProgramTwo` invocation, just add them to the recipe line.  Basically, each line of the recipe should be exactly the same as the command you'd type at your shell prompt (except you have to escape dollar signs, but you don't have any here).

Comment: Ok, this was not really what I meant, but it certainly works. I'll just stick with it instead of making things more difficult.

Comment: Well, based on your question it's not in any way clear (to me anyway) what you really wanted to do.  Are you asking how to write a program "RunAll" which itself runs the other two programs?  If so, that doesn't have anything to do with make: you need to know how to start one program from another (look into the system() function for the simplest way to do that).  Or, you could make "RunAll" a shell script which would be even simpler.  But none of this is related to make.

Comment: **Part I** You see, it works, so I'm happy (and therefore accepted your answer). But just to clarify: In the makefile that I presented I have made an executable for RunProgramOne and RunProgramTwo, which appear in my file-manager as purple diamonds after I type make in Bash. If I now type either of those two names in Bash, the program I called for gets executed. What I wanted is such a purple diamond executable that just has as a function to run both other programs after each other. In this way I could create everything from my program at once.

Comment: **Part II** Since the two previous purple diamonds were created using make, I figured the third one I had in mind, could be created in the makefile as well.

Comment: Make compiles code to create executables that can be run.  Make doesn't _write_ the code, it just compiles it.  So before make can compile code to create a `RunAll` program that will run the other two programs, someone has to write the code for that.  If you have such code then definitely make can compile it for you.  If the code is not available or if, after compilation, the program doesn't work as expected then there is nothing make can do about that: you'll have to write it or fix it.  Then make can build it for you.

Comment: So would best practice be to just use a bash script rather than make to execute files?

Comment: If what you want is a command that you can type at your shell prompt directly that runs other programs, then sure, a shell script is a good way to do that.  Of course, if you were willing to type `make RunAll` instead of just `./RunAll`, then you could write a make rule named `RunAll` that ran both the programs.  A make recipe is, in the end, just a shell script.